# why change graphic when uncomment ymin?

Tags: pgfplots, graphics

why when uncomment line "ymin = 0, ymax = 4," change graphic?

PD: Image left is comment line "ymin = 0, ymax = 4," and image right is uncomment line "ymin = 0, ymax = 4,".

[image]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.2]

    \begin{axis}[
%       xmin = 0, xmax = 4,
%       ymin = 0, ymax = 4,
        yticklabel style = {/pgf/number format/.cd,precision=1,fixed},
        axis lines = middle,
        grid = major,
        grid style = {dashed, line width=.1pt, draw=gray!30},
        legend pos = outer north east
    ]

    \addplot[
        domain = 0:2*pi,
        samples = 1000,
        no marks,
        color=blue
    ]
        {sin(deg(x))+2};

    \legend{$\sin(x)$}  

    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: pgfplots decides the plot limits itself if not specified

Comment: the question seems strange, surely if you force a different range of y values, you should expect the graph to change.

Comment: @percusse Ty for comment, you have the reason...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has been solved in comments.